# c# directiva para linq

Tags: c#

Estoy implementando una función que me traiga los años distintos de un conjunto de fechas y utilizo linq, es algo así:

```
var uniqueYears = Entidades.Ventas.Select(s => s.Fecha.Year).Distinct();
```

Me manda error en `.Year`

Estoy utilizando la directiva de linq. Alguna sugerencia?

Saludos.

Comment: ¿cúal es la definición de tu clase?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Es importante que añadas **que error** es el que te está dando.

Answer (score 4):

El problema puede ser de que `Fecha` es `Nullable<>` o puede ser nulo. Antes de utlizar la `Fecha` debes de validar con la propiedad `HasValue` de la clase `Nullable` si contiene informacion o no.

Prueba con este codigo:

```
var uniqueYears = Entidades.Ventas.Where(s => s.Fecha.HasValue).Select(s => s.Fecha.Value.Year).Distinct();
```

Primero se filtra (where) todas las fecha que no sean nulas y despues terminas seleccionando la lista fechas para obtener el año.

Documentacion de [Nullable<>](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1)

Comment: Perfecta respuesta. Gracias por tu aporte :)